# Separation of bounding boxes

Tags: python, opencv, contour, bounding-box, background-subtraction

In this problem we are trying to detect persons in a WEBCAM video in REAL TIME. The code is working fine for 1 person but when more than one person is entering then the code is failing miserably. Here is the code :-

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

kernel = np.ones((5,5), np.uint8)

background = None
while True:
    ret,frame = cap.read()
    gray = frame.copy()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(gray, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (11,11), 0)

    if background is None:
        background = gray
        continue

    delta = cv2.absdiff(background, gray)
    thresh = cv2.threshold(delta, 5, 255, 
    cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

    thresh = cv2.dilate(thresh, kernel, iterations=2)
    _,contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, 
    cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    if(len(contours)==0):
        continue

    #areas = [cv2.contourArea(c) for c in contours]
    #max_index = np.argmax(areas)
    #cnt=contours[max_index]

    #(x,y,w,h) = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)

    #if(1.0*(w*h)/(640*480)<0.75):
        #cv2.rectangle(frame, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (0,0,255), 3)
        #print("Area: ",w*h)

    for i in range(len(contours)):
        (x,y,w,h) = cv2.boundingRect(contours[i])
        if(w*h<=90000):
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (0,0,255), 5)

    #cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)

    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1)==27:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I think the problem is that the code is not able to separate the different contours of the different persons detected but I may not be the only reason. Can someone help me?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: There is no error programatically. I cant detect multiple people in the same frame. I need someone to direct me in the best possible direction to solve the problem.